# Android FFMPEG video compression issue in Samsung Galaxy S4 device

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) library to compress video in android. App gets crash when I try to compress video second time. It works fine on other android devices except Samsung Galaxy S4. It gives the following signal on crash.

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7b820a94 (code=2), thread 960 (Thread-1277)
```

I searched a lot for this issue but couldn't find solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Android ffmpeg wrappers have an issue where the second run will often cause a crash - ffmpeg was never really designed to be used this way and it looks like it is just a clean up issue at the end of each run.

There is a common trick to get around this which involved loading and unloading the library - a number of Android ffmpeg wrapper do this including:

- http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Comment: I used this library, it is crash free and I am compressing .mp4 (3 minutes video) of size 368.2MB using following command:
ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20151119_200558.mp4 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 64k -b:v 790k /storage/emulated/0/output.mp.4 but now It takes too long (I waited for 1 hour and more but still it's still compressing). How can I speed it up without affecting video quality. I pasted it here may be you can help me.

Thanks,
momersaleem